# How to change the current tab highlighter position in Android ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager witch have highlighted line in the bottom in TabLayout:

[image]

I would like to find the way to put highlighted line on top of the TabLayout as in the example:

[image]

I Googled and still googling for answer but no useful info found yet.

> My activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                local:theme="@style/ViewPagerTheme"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.pc.teltonikaapplication.fragment.DrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

If more code needed for a solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout. Just make the highlighted line align_top with TabLayout. Just use layout_align_top in RelativeLayout.

Comment: could you give me an example or something?